# What is a close option in zsh to readline's `completion-prefix-display-length`

Tags: zsh, readline

When completing, if the typed part is long, this option replaces the same part in the completion menu items with ellipsis. Especially useful if the typed part is long and there are many candidates.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01078.html), I use

```
if [[ $'\e\x5b3D' == "$(echoti cub 3)" ]] &&
   [[ $'\e\x5b33m' == "$(echoti setaf 3)" ]]; then
  zstyle -e ':completion:*' list-colors $'reply=( "=(#b)(${(b)PREFIX})(?)([^ ]#)*=0=0=${PREFIX:+${#PREFIX}D${(l:$#PREFIX:: :):-…}\e\x5b}35=33" )'
fi
zstyle ':completion:*:*(directories|files)*' list-colors ''
```

This isn't perfect, but I put in my `zshrc` and it works mostly fine